# c++ frequently open and close iostream will affect IO performance?

Tags: c++, iostream

If I want to write into a file frequently like the function of logging, which is the better way?

1. when I need to write, open iostream and close when it is done

```
void log(const string& s){
    iostream ios(log_path);
    ios << s;
    ios.close();
}
void main(){
    while (need_to_log) {
        log(some_string);
    }
}
```

2. save the file descriptor as some global variable at the beginning, use it when needed to write and close when program closes.

```
iostream ios(log_path);
void log(const string& s){
    ios << s;
}
void main(){
    while (need_to_log) {
        log(some_string);
    }
    ios.close();
}
```

Will there be a significant performance difference between those two?

Comment: `Will there be a significant performance difference` depends on what you consider as "significant" and it also depends on the used OS.

Comment: there is no `iostream::close()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there will probably be a significant difference – *if logging is what your application is spending most of its time on*.

To open and close files requires a system call. To close a file, in particular, requires the internal buffer of the `ostream` to be flushed, which requires another system call, and possibly also writing to a relatively slow disk.

In contrast, if you keep the stream open, `operator<<` just writes to an internal buffer in memory, and only writes it out when the buffer gets full. This is more efficient, but it also means you might see a delay in log lines appearing in the file. Send `std::flush` into the stream to flush earlier; note that writing `std::endl` (as opposed to simply `'\n'`) also triggers a flush.